# Related Item View - refered from child list

Tags: lookup-column

I'm working on a 2010 site at the moment and is asked to display all images to a news item (custom list). The problem is that the news don't have any reference to the Picture library, instead the Picture have a lookup to the news.

This is because the multilookup created an Issue with an integration and multiple images should be used on each newsitem. I'm aware that in this way, an image can only be used at a single news item.

Back to the problem. For the related item view to work, I'm guessing the news item must reference the Picture. Is there any way to do this "backward lookup" manually some how?

Data structure:

**NEWS**

Id

Title

**Picture Library**

Id

NewsId (lookup)

**edit**
Found that I can add a display form and create new parameter (named NewsIdParam) under the parameters button.
Then I can filter the dataformwebpart by adding a filter and map the NewsId to NewsIdParam. The problem now is that the NewsId field is a lookup and displays the "Title" from News list and the filter filters on the displayed text.